# Aggregate IDs given type min_date and max_date change through time

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to aggregate date by type through time, accounting for the changes occurred during the whole time period for the local *min_date* and *max_date* for each interval of time.

```
id  type    date
1   A       2019-01-01
1   A       2019-01-02
1   B       2019-01-03
1   B       2019-01-04
2   A       2019-01-01
2   A       2019-01-02
2   B       2019-01-03
2   A       2019-01-04
```

Code:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), type = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "C"), date = as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04"), "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

The result that I am trying to get:

```
id  type    min_date    max_date
1   A       2019-01-01  2019-01-02
1   B       2019-01-03  2019-01-04
2   A       2019-01-01  2019-01-02
2   B       2019-01-03  2019-01-03
2   A       2019-01-04  2019-01-04
```

I tired the following code, but it only shows the global *min_date* and *max_date* - not accounting for the changes through time:

```
library(dplyr)
df_changes <- df %>% group_by(id, type) %>% summarise(listings = n(), min_date = min(date), max_date = max(date))
```

Comment: ? I get the desired output when I run your code, only difference being the addition of the `listings` count.

Comment: I have given a bad example. Changed the example and you will see that id == 2 it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, as.list(range(date)) , .(id, type, grp = rleid(type))][, grp := NULL][]
#  id type         V1         V2
#1:  1    A 2019-01-01 2019-01-02
#2:  1    B 2019-01-03 2019-01-04
#3:  2    A 2019-01-01 2019-01-02
#4:  2    B 2019-01-03 2019-01-03
#5:  2    C 2019-01-04 2019-01-04
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(rleid = with(rle(type), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
 summarise(min_date = min(date),
           max_data = max(date),
           id = first(id),
           type = first(type)) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-rleid)

  min_date   max_data      id type 
  <date>     <date>     <dbl> <chr>
1 2019-01-01 2019-01-02     1 A    
2 2019-01-03 2019-01-04     1 B    
3 2019-01-01 2019-01-02     2 A    
4 2019-01-03 2019-01-03     2 B    
5 2019-01-04 2019-01-04     2 C
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 group_by(rleid = with(rle(type), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths)), id, type) %>%
 summarise(min_date = min(date),
           max_data = max(date)) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-rleid)
```

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), type = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "C"), date = as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04"), "%Y-%m-%d"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response! Unfortunately I am receiving following error for both answered codes: "Error in rle(type) : 'x' must be a vector of an atomic type". Do you know how to proceed? Many thanks!

Comment: Just include `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to your df.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I changed the example, but your code worked perfectly. Many thanks!

Comment: Did only a small change in your code: added the arrange function, because your code only work if all id are sorted: `df %>% arrange(id, date) %>% group_by(rleid = with(rle(type), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths)), id, type) %>% summarise(time_repetitions = n(), min_date = min(date), max_date = max(date)) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-rleid)`

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, just counting changes in Type so we distinguish between each time a type returns.

```
df %>%
  # New code: count how many times type is different from the prior line
  mutate(new_period = cumsum(type != lag(type,default = ""))) %>%
  group_by(id, type, new_period) %>% 

  # Orig code
  summarise(listings = n(), min_date = min(date), max_date = max(date))
```